# Graphics crop in guest welcome window

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I don't expect that any user should have noticed this, since only guests will see them.

Well, it seems that the Stack Overflow welcome splash, containing the basic info of the site, is cropped from the bottom.

[image]

Please don't mind the sides, I cropped them to fit on the screen. Just on the bottom is my concern.

Comment: Are you viewing this through cellophane?

Comment: No, office desktop.

Comment: Why are you still using Lotus Notes?

Comment: @random What do you mean by that?

Comment: It doesn't look like this when you view on a Zune

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for your feedback, this is now fixed and will be live after our next production build.